# JavaScript + JSON issue: not able to load photos/undefined.jpg

Tags: javascript, json

I am having trouble concatenating my image names in this JavaScript code. It pulls from JSON, which is making things harder for me, as a beginner. I would greatly appreciate any help! Here is my JS:

```js
 function log(msg){
    console.log(msg)
 }

function createImage(file, parent){
    var str = file;
    var filename = ("photos/"+filename+".jpg");
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = filename;
    image.style.width = "50px";
    image.style.height = "auto";
  
    image.onload = function(){
        log('good ' + file ); 
        parent.appendChild(image); //adds the image to the page!
    }
  
    image.onerror = function(){
        log('not able to load ' + filename ); 
        //parent.appendChild(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: var filename = ("photos/"+filename+".jpg"); variable filename is nowhere defined ;)

Comment: The `filename` is `undefined` at the time you do `"photos/"+filename+".jpg"`. I guess you want to use `file` instead of `filename`  here: `var filename = "photos/"+file+".jpg"`

Comment: See above comment ^^^^^^^^^ +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a confusion with the var filename and file. ;)

```
function log(msg){
     console.log(msg)
}

function createImage(file, parent){
    var str = file; // unused
    var filename = ("photos/"+file+".jpg"); // filename was undefined here.
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = file;
    image.style.width = "50px";
    image.style.height = "auto";

    image.onload = function(){
        log('good ' + file );   
        parent.appendChild(image); //adds the image to the page!
    }

    image.onerror = function(){
        log('not able to load ' + filename );   
        //parent.appendChild(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys, so much! I got it fixed! :)